# Is there a way to discover if a ParameterExpression is captured by a BlockExpression or a LambdaExpression

Tags: c#, expression

I'm writing some code to help facilitate C# method patterns in expression trees. In the case of the using block, there are three ways to use it::

```
using(var something=IDisposible_value) //1

using(something = IDisposible_value)   //2

using(something)                 //3
```

Right now my code looks like this:

```
public static Expression GenerateUsingBoilerPlate(ParameterExpression disposible,Expression toAssign,Expression body)
{
    ArgumentValidator.AssertIsNotNull(() => disposible);
 ArgumentValidator.AssertIsNotNull(() => body);

    var toDispose = Expression.Variable(typeof(IDisposable));
    Expression retVal = Expression.TryFinally(
        body,
        Expression.Block(
            new[] { toDispose },
            Expression.Assign(
                toDispose,
                Expression.TypeAs(
                    disposible,
                    typeof(IDisposable)
                )
            ),
            Expression.IfThen(
                Expression.NotEqual(
                    toDispose,
                    Expression.Default(
                        typeof(IDisposable)
                    )
                ),
                Expression.Call(
                    toDispose, 
                    "Dispose", 
                    Type.EmptyTypes
                )
            )
        )
    );
    if (toAssign != null)
    {
        retVal = Expression.Block(
            new[] { disposible },
            Expression.Assign(
                disposible ,
                toAssign
            ),
            retVal
        );
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

The problem is this code can only handle case 1 and case 3, because I have no way of knowing if the `disposible` variable is already bound somewhere else in your expression tree. Can anyone suggest a way to find out if the `ParameterExpression` is bound?

Comment: How would your code look different if you handled case 2? It looks like it already does case 2.

Comment: Right now I make the assumption that if you don't use the parameter `toAssign` then you are in case 3. If you do use the parameter you are in case 1. Case 2 would happen if you used the parameter, but `disposible` was already bound.

Comment: Could you give an example of how you would use your boiler plate method?

Comment: The `foreach` loop is my current only example. The `IEnumerator<T>` is IDisposible, since I was already building the loop as boiler plate I abstracted out the using statement. Thus the body of my foreach reads::     `return Expression.Block(
    new[] { currentVariable },
    ExpressionHelper.GenerateUsingBoilerPlate(
     enumerator,
     getEnumeratorCall,
     ExpressionHelper.GenerateWhileLoopBoilerPlate(
      moveNextExpression,
      Expression.Block(
       assignCurrent,
       body
      ),
      @break
     )`

Comment: I kind of see what you are doing.  Is the 'enumerator' ParameterExpression passed to you as a parameter at this point?  Or are you creating the 'enumerator'?

Comment: In the case of a foreach loop the `IEnumerator<T>` is something I create given a `IEnumerable`

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the variable **toDispose** (serving as **something** in your **using** example) for two of the three cases, but only one of your cases actually declares the variable (case #1).  The other two cases assume that the variable is already declared somewhere else.  So, can you make **toDispose** a parameter to your **GenerateUsingBoilerPlate** method and then if it is null, create **toDispose**?

This doesn't answer your question on how to determine if the **disposible** variable is already bound, but can you not simply assume/require that it be bound?  Then Case#1 and Case#2 work.  Case#3 doesn't use **disposible**, it instead uses **toDispose**.

**EDIT**
In otherwords, you don't need to know if **disposible** is bound, instead you require it to be bound (if supplied).  If not supplied, then you require that **toDispose** be supplied.

Comment: How can I use toDispose then if its null? It'll throw an argument null exception.

Comment: If toDispose is passed in as null, then create your own local expression for the variable and assign it.  If it is not a null expression, then assume it's bound.  If at expression run-time, the toDispose is null, then let it throw an exception.

Comment: Then its absolutely useless if its null how do you use it? How does it get disposed? I'm not sure this will work.

Comment: I don't believe it's useless, but I also don't believe we are communicating well.  So disregard this answer and see my next answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are actually 4 different ways the using could be called.  The examples and numbers below roughly correspond to your numbers except I added #4...

```
using (var a = File.CreateText(@"c:\temp\test.txt"))  //#1
{
    // a is only visible in this context
}
TextWriter w;
using(w = File.CreateText(@"c:\temp\test.txt")) //#2
{
    // w is visible outside of this context, but is only valid within the context
}
w = File.CreateText(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
using (w)                                       //#3
{
    // w is visible outside of this context, but is only valid between assignment and end of this context
}
using (File.CreateText(@"c:\temp\test.txt"))    //#4
{
    // the disposable is not visible in any context
}
```

I would recommend that you take a look at the **Expression.CatchBlock(...)** method and see how the parameters are passed to it.  The **catch** statement is similar in that a local variable is declared to be used within the statement.  That might mean that your **UsingBoilerPlate** might look more like this...

```
public static Expression<Action> UsingBoilerPlate(
                 Expression disposeExpression,
                 Expression bodyExpression,
                 ParameterExpression localVariable,
                 bool unbound) { ... }
public static Expression<Action> UsingBoilerPlate(
                 Expression disposeExpression,
                 Expression bodyExpression,
                 ParameterExpression localVariable)
{  return UsingBoilerPlate(disposeExpression, bodyExpression, localVariable, true); }
public static Expression<Action> UsingBoilerPlate(
                 Expression disposeExpression,
                 Expression bodyExpression)
{  return UsingBoilerPlate(disposeExpression, bodyExpression, null); }
```

To handle each of the 4 scenarios, you would call it like this...

```
var action1 =
    Expression.Lambda<Action>
    (
        Using
        (
            disposableExpression,
            bodyExpression,
            localVariable
        )
    );
action1.Compile()();

var action2 =
    Expression.Lambda<Action>
    (
        Expression.Block
        (
            new [] { localVariable },
            new Expression[] {
                Using
                (
                    disposableExpression,
                    bodyExpression,
                    localVariable,
                    false
                ),
                Expression.IfThenElse(
                    Expression.NotEqual(
                        localVariable, Expression.Constant(null)),
                    ((Expression<Action>)(() => Console.WriteLine("w is NOT null"))).Body,
                    ((Expression<Action>)(() => Console.WriteLine("w is null"))).Body
                )
            }
        )
    );
action2.Compile()();
```

The next example uses a little trick where `using(w)` is equivalent to `using(w = w)`

```
var action3 =
    Expression.Lambda<Action>
    (
        Expression.Block
        (
            new [] { localVariable },
            new Expression[] {
                Expression.Assign(localVariable, disposeExpression);
                Using
                (
                    localVariable,
                    bodyExpression,
                    localVariable,
                    false
                ),
                Expression.IfThenElse(
                    Expression.NotEqual(
                        localVariable, Expression.Constant(null)),
                    ((Expression<Action>)(() => Console.WriteLine("w is NOT null"))).Body,
                    ((Expression<Action>)(() => Console.WriteLine("w is null"))).Body
                )
            }
        )
    );
action3.Compile()();
```

And last,

```
var action4 =
    Expression.Lambda<Action>
    (
        Using
        (
            disposableExpression,
            bodyExpression
        )
    );
action4.Compile()();
```

So, you can't really figure out if a ParameterExpression is bound external to your method, but you can tell your method whether it is nor not.